# next js redux-observable persistent auth token using cookie

Tags: authentication, cookies, authorization, redux-observable, next.js

I have been trying to implement [react](https://reactjs.org/) server-side-rendering using [next](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/), and [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/), now i want to implement auth

**On signin**

- click signin

  - dispatch signin

    - set signin type
    - set signin data
  - call backend api auth/signin

    - if the response says that token is expired

      - call backed api auth/refresh using refreshToken
      - set cookie based on auth/refresh response token
      - set auth data based on auth/refresh response
    - else

      - set cookie based on auth/signin response token
      - set auth data based on auth/signin response

**On accessing pages that needs auth**

- check for cookies called `token`

  - if exists

    - call backed api auth/me to authorize
    - if the response says that token is expired

      - call backed api auth/refresh using refreshToken
      - set cookie based on auth/refresh response token
      - set auth data based on auth/refresh
    - else

      - set auth data based on auth/me response
  - else

    - redirect to signin

Steps above happens inside the epics, as follows

`/epics/signin.js`

```
export const signinEpic = (action$, store) => action$
  .ofType(SIGNIN)
  .mergeMap(() => {
    const params = { ... }
    return ajax(params)
      .concatMap((response) => {
        const { name, refreshToken } = response.body
        if (refreshToken && name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
          const refreshParams = { ... }
          return ajax(refreshParams)
            .concatMap((refreshResponse) => {
              setToken(refreshResponse.body.auth.token)
              const me = { ... }
              return [
                authSetMe(me),
                signinSuccess(),
              ]
            })
            .catch(error => of(signinFailure(error)))
        }
        const me = { ... }
        setToken(response.body.auth.token)
        return [
          authSetMe(me),
          signinSuccess(),
        ]
      })
      .catch(error => of(signinFailure(error)))
  })
```

I did some `console.log(Cookies.get('token'))` to ensure that the cookie gets saved, and it prints the token just fine, saying that its there, but when i checked under browser console > Application > Cookies, nothing is there

So in auth epic below, the `getToken()` will always return `''` which will always dispatch `authMeFailure(error)`

`/epics/auth.js`

```
// this epic will run on pages that requires auth by dispatching `authMe()`
export const authMeEpic = action$ => action$
  .ofType(AUTH_ME)
  .mergeMap(() => {
    const params = {
      ...,
      data: {
        ...
        Authorization: getToken() ? getToken() : '', // this will always return ''
      },
    }
    return ajax(params)
      .mergeMap((response) => {
        const { name, refreshToken } = response.body
        if (refreshToken && name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
          const refreshParams = { ... }
          return ajax(refreshParams)
            .mergeMap((refreshResponse) => {
              setToken(refreshResponse.body.auth.token)
              const me = { ... }
              return authMeSuccess(me)
            })
            .catch(error => of(authMeFailure(error)))
        }
        const me = { ... }
        setToken(response.body.auth.token)
        return authMeSuccess(me)
      })
      .catch(error => of(authMeFailure(error)))
  })
```

I use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for getting and setting cookies

**EDIT:** i actually prepared an auth lib containing getToken, setToken and removeToken, as follows

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export const isAuthenticated = () => {
  const token = Cookies.get('token')
  return !!token
}

export const getToken = () => Cookies.get('token')

export const setToken = token => Cookies.set('token', token)

export const removeToken = () => Cookies.remove('token')
```

and yes, i could have just used the `setToken()` on the epics, was just trying to directly test the cookie set method

**UPDATE:**

- it seems that despite its not being in Console > Application > Cookies, its exists on every pages as it's printing the correct token if i do `console.log(getToken())` inside the component render method
- But every time i refresh the page, its gone. Kind of like it is being stored in a redux state, which is weird

**UPDATE #2:**

ok i think i manage to make it work, it turns out that we need 2 types of cookie, server side (the one's generated on refresh) and a client side (persist on navigating), so the reason that i wasn't able to get the token on epics its because it was not passed from the server side (at least this is my understanding)

Comment: Can you try to delete { path: '/' } from the Cookies.set? Just to make sure it's not an issue with the path.

Comment: wow! you're right, its the path, i am so ashamed of myself right now, thanks btw!

Comment: No, i am sorry its still not working, don't know how it seems like its working previously

Comment: Try to remove the {path} options in all Cookies.set  Also could you please provide the code of getToken() ?

Comment: i did remove all {path} options, btw question updated with lib/auth.js

Comment: Try cookies.get() without arguments and see if it returns something

Comment: it returns an object { token: "the token" }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167258/discussion-between-luispinto-and-littlechad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this issue [comment](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/153#issuecomment-370583952) on github

`yarn add cookie-parser`

on `./server.js` (you need to have a custom server to be able to do this)

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

...

server.use(cookieParser())
```

on `./pages/_document.js`

```
export default class extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(...args) {
    // ...args in your case would probably be req
    const token = args[0].req ? getServerToken(args[0].req) : getToken()

    return {
      ...
      token,
    }
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

on `./lib/auth.js` or on any place you put your token methods

```
export const getServerToken = (req) => {
  const { token = '' } = req.cookies

  return token
}

export const getToken = () => {
  return Cookies.get('token') ? Cookies.get('token') : ''
}
```

I am not 100% understand how this is solving my problem, but i am gonna leave it like this for now